# Создание достижения в Google Play Games Api (совершить 100 000 перемещений)

Tags: android, разработка-игр, google-play

Имеется игра 15 (Пятнашки). Хочу сделать достижение  (Achievement) заключающееся в 100 000 перемещений костей. increment достижения (для которых требуется несколько шагов) имеют максимальное количество шагов в 10 000. Вот и вопрос, как реализовать такое ачивку с 100 000 перемещений?

Comment: что имено у вас не получается? Неужели, посчитать перемещения?

Answer (score 2):

Считайте перемещения сами. Каждые, например, 1000 перемещений увеличивайте счетчик достижения на +1. Итого у вас будет ачивка - сделать "100 тысяч" перемещений вместо "100 000" перемещений.